# About confusion in NSTimer class methods

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am beginner in iphone...

what is the difference between

```
+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

and

```
+ timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

also for

```
+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:
```

and

```
+ timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:
```

i will use both way but in which case i use with class method of NSTimer?....

Answer (score 2):

1. `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats`:

Will start the NSTimer **immediately** And will return `NSTimer`

2.
    `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats`:

Will return you `NSTimer` and You should so something to make it start.

Like `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Don't forget to invalidate your timer like:

```
-(void)stopTimer {
   [self.timer invalidate];
   [self.timer = nil];
}
```